# Is the angular velocity of a wave constant?

Tags: waves, frequency

For a given wave, how does the angular frequency vary? For example, if the wave starts propagating at $x=0$ with angular frequency $\omega$, then at another point in the $x$ direction, does this angular velocity remain same ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! What sort of "wave" are you considering here? What is your definition of "angular velocity" of this wave? Also, please consider writing more useful question titles, see [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583)

Answer (score 1):

$\omega=2\pi f$ so angular frequency depends only on frequency. And frequency depends only on the source that produces it, that is, it is not a function of time or position. So angular frequency is constant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PhysicsSE! Please use TeX for formulas.